# What is CUDA like? What is it for? What are the benefits? And how to start?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

I am interested in developing under some new technology and I was thinking in trying out CUDA. Now... their documentation is too technical and doesn't provide the answers I'm looking for. Also, I'd like to hear those answers from people that've had some experience with CUDA already.

Basically my questions are those in the title:

> What exactly IS CUDA? (is it a framework? Or an API? What?)
>
> What is it for? (is there something more than just programming to the GPU?)
>
> What is it like?
>
> What are the benefits of programming against CUDA instead of programming to the CPU?
>
> What is a good place to start programming with CUDA?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

CUDA brings together several things:

- Massively parallel hardware designed to run generic (non-graphic) code, with appropriate drivers for doing so.
- A programming language based on C for programming said hardware, and an assembly language that other programming languages can use as a target.
- A software development kit that includes libraries, various debugging, profiling and compiling tools, and bindings that let CPU-side programming languages invoke GPU-side code.

The point of CUDA is to write code that can run on compatible massively parallel SIMD architectures: this includes several GPU types as well as non-GPU hardware such as nVidia Tesla. Massively parallel hardware can run a significantly larger number of operations per second than the CPU, at a fairly similar financial cost, yielding performance improvements of 50× or more in situations that allow it.

One of the benefits of CUDA over the earlier methods is that a general-purpose language is available, instead of having to use pixel and vertex shaders to emulate general-purpose computers. That language is based on C with a few additional keywords and concepts, which makes it fairly easy for non-GPU programmers to pick up.

It's also a sign that nVidia is willing to support general-purpose parallelization on their hardware: it now sounds less like "hacking around with the GPU" and more like "using a vendor-supported technology", and that makes its adoption easier in presence of non-technical stakeholders.

To start using CUDA, download the SDK, read the manual (seriously, it's not *that* complicated if you already know C) and buy CUDA-compatible hardware (you *can* use the emulator at first, but performance being the ultimate point of this, it's better if you can actually try your code out)

Comment: Don't forget that CUDA cannot benefit every program/algorithm: the CPU is good in performing complex/different operations in relatively small numbers (i.e. < 10 threads/processes) while the full power of the GPU is unleashed when it can do simple/the same operations on massive numbers of threads/data points (i.e. > 10.000).

That's why it's so good in e.g. video decoding/encoding: those are the same simple operations on a large number of pixels (almost a million in 720p)

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I have only used CUDA for a semester project in 2008, so things might have changed since then.) CUDA is a development toolchain for creating programs that can run on nVidia GPUs, as well as an API for controlling such programs from the CPU.

The benefits of GPU programming vs. CPU programming is that for some highly parallelizable problems, you can gain *massive* speedups (about two orders of magnitude faster). However, many problems are difficult or impossible to formulate in a manner that makes them suitable for parallelization.

In one sense, CUDA is fairly straightforward, because you can use regular C to create the programs. However, in order to achieve good performance, a lot of things must be taken into account, including many low-level details of the Tesla GPU architecture.